# Visual Studio Lags when application starts up

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

I'm using XNA create a game, recently Visual Studios started lagging when I start the application. It wasn't like this early today which is surprising.

I was wondering if there was a cache that I might need to delete or something that might need to be cleared in order for it to run more smoothly

Comment: What happens after a computer restart?

Comment: that didn't change anything

Comment: have you enabled "unmanaged code debugging" or intellitrace? both of these can cause VS to do a lot during debugging.

Comment: i see that "unmanaged code debugging" is disabled but how do I find out if intellitrace is enabled?

Comment: i think i found the cause of the delay, anytime it loads something from Content, like a texture or mp3 it delays a little

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I faced a similar problem with very long loading times, resetting all Visual Studio settings helped.

I still haven't found out what exactly my problem was caused by, but I suspect it was one of my Visual Studio extensions.

Have you installed any extensions, plugins or something unusual?

---

If it is the content compilation that causes such a lag, you could disable compilation of compiled content, since you've already done that and it hasn't been changed.